# How to thicken the font of the formula?

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

How to thicken the font of the formula embedded in text

```
total de: $1.6\times0$
```

the result is:

[image]

the multiplication has a dull black color, I do not want that color change to exist

Comment: I suspect that's due to antialiasing done in part by your PDF/EPS viewer.  Zoom in and see?

Comment: It is unclear if you think that LaTeX changes color by it self - it does not. ...or if you are looking for reasons why you should change color - you should not. Please make a MWE and try different viewers.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I do not want that color change to exist

Comment: Then you are in luck, because it does not exist, unless you have done something to make it happen yourself. Please look at the output in different viewers and zoom in.

Comment: @hubman I compiled my own Minimal Working Environment code. Did you zoom in, for example, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwROk.png)?

Comment: @FrenzyLi i edited my question, with 150% of zoom

Comment: Did you try 800% zoom or higher, and check if the symbol is filled with black color? If it is, the symbol **is already colored in black**. You could make your $\times$ bolder, larger, etc. but they may look bad.

Comment: @FrenzyLi 
I think that only the source is thinner?

Comment: @hubman Yes. Instead of asking why the color changed, it's probably better to modify your question.

Comment: You appear to have changed the text font from computer modern to something else.  Pick a matching math font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you've loaded a package that provides an Helvetica *text font* clone. If you want the math material to use the same sans-serif glyphs, you can do so by loading the `sansmath` package and issuing the instruction `\sansmath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}   % sans-serif text font
\usepackage{sansmath} % sans-serif math font 
\begin{document}
\sffamily\sansmath
total de: $1{,}6\times 0$ 

\textit{abcde} $abcde$

01234 $01234$
\end{document}
```